# Why can't I use custom font with Material Design Lite?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, material-design-lite

Today I learned how to use Material Design Lite. But I have a problem: I can't use custom font. How can I fix something like this?

If I delete `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material.min%202.css" />` from my file, it will change my font into `Raleway`. But if I still use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material.min%202.css" />`, it will replace my font with default.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material.min%202.css" />
        <style>
            @font-face{ 
                font-family: 'Raleway';
                src: url('WebFont.eot');
                src: url('./fonts/raleway-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
                    url('./fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
            }
            .container{
                font-family: 'Raleway';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="centered">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
                    Button
                </button>
                <h2>Harap segera lakukan verifikasi email anda untuk bisa melanjutkan ketahap berikutnya.</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
       <script src="js/material.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `font-family: 'Raleway' !important;`.

Comment: still same, can't change font.

Comment: OK. `.container *{
                font-family: 'Raleway' !important;
            }`?

Comment: wow, it works. Btw, what * do in css ?

Comment: Cool. `*` is an selector for `all`. In your case all `children` of `.container`. It was a bit tricky. Because `Material` sets its own font. And it might get loaded after your `style`. So you want to be hard. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

1. The file fonts you are referencing do not resolve (the links are wrong or the files are corrupted/invalid/truncated) - this should create some entries in your console log (most browsers issue warnings whenever they are unable to resolve resources)
2. You have a stronger selector applying a different rule to the element you are trying to style (right-click > *"Inspect element"* > find `font-family` value and what is setting it - most browsers allow you this type of inspection; if your does not, use Chrome or Firefox).
   **Very important:** Please note that, even if you specify a `font-family` for a parent, if the child has a specified `font-family` it will ignore **any** `font-family` coming from parents, regardless of selector strength in parent rule.
   For example:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace !important;
}
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>I am &lt;p>.</p>
<div>I am not &lt;p>.</div>
```

will give `<p>` elements inside your `<body>` a value of `sans-serif` and not `monospace`, as you'd expect.

Most likely, you need to find the rule setting `font-family` for your element(s) and override it at the same (parent) level or below (in a child). Trying to override it from above where it is currently set will not work.

A good trick in overriding `font-family` from parent level is to use

```
parentSelector * { 
  font-family: value !important; 
}
```

... as this will match any rule set at child level, and the `!important` will get applied:

```css
body * {
  font-family: monospace !important;
}
p#some-id {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p id="some-id">I am &lt;p>.</p>
<div>I am not &lt;p>.</div>
```

In this example `body *` and `p#some-id` are referring to same child and the stronger selector (`!important`) gets applied.

Comment: Thanks, few people ask about this on MDL repo, mostly they don't get answer. I hope this question and answer will help people who need it. Sorry for my bad english.